# How to handle killed (closed) App state for notification in IOS Swift 2

Tags: ios, notifications, swift2, apple-push-notifications

I'm new on IOS programming. I have issues handle notification in IOS Swift 2. I send notification from server, when App don't killed (Equivalent in Android `onPause()`) I can notification handle and open App works normally, go to notification url. When I killed App (Equivalent in Android `onDestroy()`) notification handle don't work, App open and close (Equivalent in Android `onPause()`) automatic and App works on background and don't going notification url.

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print(userInfo)
    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        let link_url:String = (aps["link_url"] as? String)!

        self.notifUrl = link_url
        if(!self.appActive! && self.mainView != nil) {
            self.mainView?.loadLink(link_url)
        }
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        let link_url:String = (aps["link_url"] as? String)!

        self.notifUrl = link_url
        if(!self.appActive! && self.mainView != nil) {
            self.mainView?.loadLink(link_url)
        }
    }
}
```

> NOTE: When I killed App SIGKILL error.

Whats problem? How can I fix it? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thats the expected behavior. If an app is terminated pushes don't get delivered to it (unless its a voip push).

If its a foreground push it will be delivered to the user, if its a background push it will not get delivered to anything.

If its a foreground push and it gets delivered to the user, then if and when the user taps on the notification then your app will get launched.

Comment: All time (app killed or not) notification delivered device, but when App killed I can't open App from notification action

Comment: It wasn't clear that that was your actual question. In that case it must be a problem with your code. When the app is being launched from a terminated state via a notification it is not didReceiveRemoteNotification that gets called, instead it is didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: with a specific launchOptions parameter. Check the documentation for this and check your code for didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to see if there's an error.

Comment: Thanks for direction. ` 
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
_ = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
 let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
return true
    }`

Comment: Too difficult to read, update your original question please. You can also add some print() statements ti addDidLaunch and your code that comes after that to help determine where the problem occurs.